# Como puedo imprimir el nombre en un ArrayList JAVA NetBeans

Tags: java

Tengo este código ArrayList de JAVA en NetBeans con cinco estudiantes, cada uno con las mismas materias, entonces como hago para que al final me imprima la edad mayor con el nombre del estudiante?
La edad ya la tengo solo me falta poder imprimir el nombre del estudiante

```
ArrayList listaEstudiantes = new ArrayList();
        Estudiante estudiante1 = new Estudiante();
        Estudiante estudiante2 = new Estudiante();


        estudiante1.codigo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el código del estudiante 1: ");
        estudiante1.nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante 1: ");
        estudiante1.Apellido = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el apellido del estudiante 1: ");
        estudiante1.edad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la edad del estudiante 1: "))

        listaEstudiantes.add(estudiante1);

        estudiante2.codigo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el código del estudiante 2: ");
        estudiante2.nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante 2: ");
        estudiante2.Apellido = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el apellido del estudiante 2: ");
        estudiante2.edad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la edad del estudiante 2: "));

        listaEstudiantes.add(estudiante2);

        listaEstudiantes.add(estudiante5);

        for (int i = 0; i < listaEstudiantes.size(); i++) {
            Estudiante auxEst = (Estudiante) listaEstudiantes.get(i);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, "Codigo # : " + auxEst.codigo + ", Nombre y Apellido: " + auxEst.nombre + " " + auxEst.Apellido + ", Edad: " + auxEst.edad + ", Nota de algoritmia: " + auxEst.notaAlgoritmia + ", Nota de Introduccion: " + auxEst.notaIntroduccion + ", Nota de Pensamiento: " + auxEst.notaPensamiento);

        }

        int indice1 = 0;
        int mayor;
        mayor = estudiante5.edad;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaEstudiantes.size(); i++) {
            Estudiante auxEst = (Estudiante) listaEstudiantes.get(i);

            if (auxEst.edad > mayor) {
                mayor = auxEst.edad;
                indice1 = i;
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La mayor edad es: " + mayor);

    }
```

Comment: Copia y pega tu código para poder ayudarte mejor .

Comment: Hola bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, porfavor revisa el [tour] y de paso lee [ask] para poder ayudarte y que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Es la primera vez que uso esta pagina, no se en donde copiar el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si obtuviste el indice del objeto que contiene la mayor edad (`indice1`), puedes usar este valor para obtener el objeto que deseas y sus propiedades.

```
    ...
    ...
    //Obtiene estudiante en base a indice.
    Estudiante mayorEstudiante = (Estudiante) listaEstudiantes.get(indice1);

    //Muestra datos de estudiante de mayor edad.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La mayor edad es: " + mayorEstudiante.edad + " nombre: " + mayorEstudiante.nombre);

}
```

Comment: Me aparece error

Comment: Que error se muestra? es importante especificar,  agrega como te sugería el objeto Estudiante,saludosl

Comment: Me aparece: Cannot find symbol, variable mayorEstudiante

Comment: "Cannot find symbol" pero cual es la variable que no encuentra?, trata de ser especifico, edita tu pregunta y agrega el objeto Estudiante por favor.

Comment: La variable que no encuentra es "mayorEstudiante".

Comment: Debes agregar arriba de  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.... el obtener el objeto : Estudiante mayorEstudiante = (Estudiante) listaEstudiantes.get(indice1); ya que es otro objeto , NO debes agregarlo dentro del for o del If.

Comment: Ah okey, no sabia, empece hace poco en esto, muchas gracias :)

Comment: No te preocupes todos iniciamos desde 0, te sugiero siempre agregar la información necesaria en tus preguntas eso ayudará a que la comunidad te ayude más rápido y mejor, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una variable que se vaya seteando al mismo tiempo que seteas la edad. algo asi:

```
    int indice1 = 0;
    int mayor;
    String nombre;        <-----
    mayor = estudiante5.edad;
    for (int i = 0; i < listaEstudiantes.size(); i++) {
        Estudiante auxEst = (Estudiante) listaEstudiantes.get(i);

        if (auxEst.edad > mayor) {
            mayor = auxEst.edad;
            nombre = auxEst.nombre;  <------
            indice1 = i;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La mayor edad es: " + mayor);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su nombre es: " + nombre);
```